# exclude files from logrotate

Tags: glob, logrotate

my goal is to create a `logrotate` configuration which specifies a different rotation number for each set of log files. 10 for the first set, 14 for the second set, 5 for all the rest. this is what i have so far:

```
~/log/myLog1*.log{
   rotate 10
   ...
}

~/log/myLog2*.log {
   rotate 14
   ...
}

~/log/[!{myLog1,myLog2}]*.log {
   rotate 5
   ...
}
```

the following shows the files i want to rotate:

```
ls ~/log/[!{myLog1,myLog2}]*.log
```

but because `logrotate` [doesn't support extended globbing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83859), the 3rd pattern doesn't work and i get this error message

```
rotating pattern: ~/log/[! forced from command line (5 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log ~/log/[!
  log ~/log/[! does not exist -- skipping
```

can anyone correct my final pattern so that it works?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using excluding with prerotate? Following example is untested.

```
~/log/*.log {
   rotate 5
   nosharedscripts
   prerotate
       bash -c "[[ ! $1 =~ myLog1.log ]] && [[ ! $1 =~ myLog2.log ]]"
   endscript
}
~/log/myLog1.log {
   rotate 10
}
~/log/myLog1.log {
   rotate 14
}
```

[source](https://web.archive.org/web/20211018113637/https://paperairoplane.net/posts/excluding-files-from-logrotate-globbing-matches)